# PHPExcel: Excel cannot open file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am generating a excel sheet from the code below:

```
$k = 3;//Three rows made outside loop
while($i<n){
    if(<condition>){
        //the code here works fine
    }else{
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                    ->setCellValue('A'.($i+$k), detailedTaskActivitiesMap($i))
                    ->setCellValue('B'.($i+$k), " ")
                    ->setCellValue('C'.($i+$k), " ")
                    ->setCellValue('D'.($i+$k), " ")
                    ->setCellValue('E'.($i+$k), " ")
                    ->setCellValue('F'.($i+$k), " ")
                    ->setCellValue('G'.($i+$k), " ")
                    ->setCellValue('H'.($i+$k), " ")
                    ->setCellValue('I'.($i+$k), " ")
                    ->setCellValue('J'.($i+$k), " ")
                    ->setCellValue('K'.($i+$k), " ")
                    ->setCellValue('L'.($i+$k), " ")
                    ->setCellValue('M'.($i+$k), " ")
                    ->setCellValue('N'.($i+$k), " ")
                    ->setCellValue('O'.($i+$k), " ")
                    ->setCellValue('P'.($i+$k), " ")
                    ->setCellValue('Q'.($i+$k), " ")
                    ->setCellValue('R'.($i+$k), " ")
                    ->setCellValue('S'.($i+$k), " ");
        $sharedStyleA1 = new PHPExcel_Style();
        $sharedStyleA1->applyFromArray(array('fill' => array(
                                    'type'  => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                                    'color' => array('argb' => 'FFf2f2f2')
                                   ),
                      'borders' => array('bottom'=> array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,'color' => array('argb' => 'FFbfbfbf'))
                                   )
                      ));
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setSharedStyle($sharedStyleA1, "A".($i+$k));

        $sharedStyleRest1 = new PHPExcel_Style();
        $sharedStyleRest1->applyFromArray(array('fill' => array(
                                    'type'  => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                                    'color' => array('argb' => 'FFffffff')
                                   ),
                      'borders' => array(
                                    'left'=> array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,'color' => array('argb' => 'FFbfbfbf')),
                                    'bottom'=> array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,'color' => array('argb' => 'FFbfbfbf')),
                                    'right'=> array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK,'color' => array('argb' => 'FF000000'))
                                   )
                      ));
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setSharedStyle($sharedStyleRest1, "S".($i+$k));
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.($i+$k))->getFont()->setSize(10);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.($i+$k))->getFont()->setSize(8);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.($i+$k))->getFont()->getColor()->applyFromArray( array('argb' => 'FF000000','name'=>'Calibri') );
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.($i+$k))->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.($i+$k))->getFont()->getColor()->applyFromArray( array('argb' => 'FFc00000','name'=>'Calibri') );
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.($i+$k))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.($i+$k))->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);


    }
    $i++;
}

//Code to generate other rows.

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:S100')
        ->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true); 

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');

exit();
```

Whenever their is a row for which the if condition fails the excel sheet fails to open in Microsoft Excel.

I have tested for the values of $i,$k, and the values returned by other functions and variables. They are correct.

Comment: You need to take your `objPHPExcel` and create a file using one of the PHPExcel interfaces, are you doing that?

Comment: Try some basic debugging remove half of the stuff it does if the condition fails and try again, if that works then you know which half is causing the problem if not then try it with the other half of the stuff there and removing and adding bits till you find out exactly what is causing the problem.

Comment: @DevZer0 - I have updated the code on how I am creating file.

Comment: @Anigel - I have tried all combinations possible, starting from no code in else block to only inserting values in cell and no styling to no values and only styling.

Comment: Have you tried it with the known good code from the condition passing?

Comment: @Anigel - The code in the else block is similar to the one in if. Only a little modified. But I'll try out your suggestion.

Comment: @Anigel - The piece of code where i insert values into the cells is a standard way to input text. If remove everything else and just keep that part, the output is the same for any value within quotes.